# How do I use an Alias in my Acess report

Tags: ms-access, report, alias

I've created an alias in my Access SQL query, it shows fine as a valid column when I run my query, but when I try and use that field in my report, it reverts back to the original name and value. How do I make the report pull in the value of the alias returned in my record stack? Will I have to do this through VBA?

This is the query which is my report's *Record Source*:

```sql
SELECT
    ISO_ID.ISOID,
    ISO_Stats.TransactionCount,
    ISO_Stats.TerminalCount,
    ISO_Stats.MonthEnd,
    m2.TerminalCount,
    m2.TransactionCount,
    m2.MonthEnd,
    m3.TerminalCount,
    m3.TransactionCount,
    m3.MonthEnd
FROM
    (((ISO_ID
    INNER JOIN ISO_Stats AS m2
    ON ISO_ID.[ISOID] = m2.[ISOID])
    INNER JOIN ISO_Stats
    ON (ISO_ID.ISOID = ISO_Stats.ISOID) AND (ISO_ID.InstNbr = ISO_Stats.InstNbr))
    INNER JOIN ISO_Stats AS m3
    ON ISO_ID.[ISOID] = m3.[ISOID])
WHERE
        (((ISO_Stats.MonthEnd)=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0))
    AND ((m2.MonthEnd)=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,0))
    AND ((m3.MonthEnd)=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-2,0))
    AND ((ISO_ID.Cancelled)<>"Y") )
ORDER BY ISO_ID.ISOName;
```

Comment: Yes. I go into Report Properties and get to the query from the Data source. It shows as an available field and shows correctly on the design view. However, when I view the report, it shows the value of the original field. When I go back into design view, the data source for that label then reflects the original field.

Comment: Actually have three that I've created, using inner joins, which I probably should have mentioned, and all three are acting the same way.

Comment: SELECT ISO_ID.ISOID, ISO_Stats.TransactionCount, ISO_Stats.TerminalCount, ISO_Stats.MonthEnd, 
m2.TerminalCount, m2.TransactionCount, m2.MonthEnd, 
m3.TerminalCount, m3.TransactionCount, m3.MonthEnd

Comment: FROM (((ISO_ID 
 INNER JOIN ISO_Stats AS m2 ON ISO_ID.[ISOID] = m2.[ISOID]) 
 INNER JOIN ISO_Stats ON (ISO_ID.ISOID = ISO_Stats.ISOID) AND (ISO_ID.InstNbr = ISO_Stats.InstNbr)) 
 INNER JOIN ISO_Stats AS m3 ON ISO_ID.[ISOID] = m3.[ISOID])

Comment: WHERE 
 ( 
  ((ISO_Stats.MonthEnd)=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)) AND 
  ((m2.MonthEnd)=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,0)) AND 
  ((m3.MonthEnd)=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-2,0)) AND
  ((ISO_ID.Cancelled)<>"Y")
 )
ORDER BY ISO_ID.ISOName;

Comment: The fields I'm trying to put on my report are the ISO_Stats.TransactionCount and TerminalCount, and the corresponding M1 and M2 fields. It let's me on the Design View, but when I run the report, the values from the ISO_Stats fields are populated in all labels. I go back into Design View and see the Data Source is back to the ISO_Stats field.

Comment: When I do a Run, from the DB Query Builder, all fields are populated with the correct values expected for the three months.

Answer (score 1):

Your query's `SELECT` column list includes duplicate column names.  Use aliases so that the column names in the query result set are distinct:

```sql
SELECT
    ISO_ID.ISOID,
    ISO_Stats.TransactionCount AS [TransactionCount_i],
    ISO_Stats.TerminalCount AS [TerminalCount_i],
    ISO_Stats.MonthEnd AS [MonthEnd_i],
    m2.TerminalCount AS [TerminalCount_2],
    m2.TransactionCount AS [TransactionCount_2],
    m2.MonthEnd AS [MonthEnd_2],
    m3.TerminalCount AS [TerminalCount_3],
    m3.TransactionCount AS [TransactionCount_3],
    m3.MonthEnd AS [MonthEnd_3]
```

You will need to revise the report to use those aliased column names, but then you should be able to avoid the report's confusion when dealing with duplicate column names.

Comment: Perfect! Works great.